# MS-CRM 2013 Prevent user to move on next stage

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on Business Process Flow. I have created flow **Contact--Opportunity--Quote--Order--Invoice** as per the requirement. Entity **Opportunity** have attribute **Budget Amount**, If the budget amount is less than 300,000 user should not move to next stage. My question is how to prevent an user to move to next stage. I am writing plugin to do so.

Comment: I believe you could also accomplish this using business rules.  Create a yes/no field that defaults to no and must be yes in order to move to the next stage.  Then create business rules that set the value to yes if the budget amount is set to more than 300k and no if the budget amount is set to less than 300k.

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Register the plugin to Pre-Update Operation of Opportunity.
2. Check for `stageid` field:

   ```
   if (!context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && 
       context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
   {
      Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
      if (target .Attributes.Contains("stageid") && 
          target ["stageid"] != null
      {
          // check stage value match your next stage

          // check Budget Amount

          // if Budget Amount < 300000 throw an exception
      }
   }
   ```
3. Check next stage value, there are 2 ways to check the stage

   -Retrieve the next stage id by your stage name, and compare if they are match then go on to the next step, else return. Or,

   -Create a new field called `stagename` to store the stage name, and a CRM workflow triggered when `stageid` field changed to update this field with Process Stage Name. [Detail here](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2014/07/09/display-business-process-values-forms-crm-2013/). Then, you have a stage name available to check without having to retrieve it. Compare if value in your new field are match the next stage name then go on to the next step, else return.
4. Retrieve and check Budget Amount value. Or, if you don't want to retrieve, you can use pre-image and/or target['budgetamount'] to get the value.
5. If Budget Amount < 300000, then

   ```
   throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Budget Amount must be greater than 300,000 to move to the next stage");
   ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Edit programmatically business process flow:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2013/09/20/how-to-change-process-and-stage-programmatically.aspx